# FeatureLayer creation using ArcGIS JS Api with data hosted on ArcGIS online

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

I have a few feature layers hosted on ArcGIS Online and I am trying to add feature layer editing to my web project. The JS API guide says the data must come from an ArcSDE geodatabase (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/inside_editing.html), but i am hoping they just aren't telling us everything...

I have done a bit of research on this and can't really find any info on it or examples of anyone doing this.

Does anyone know if its possible to do feature creation/editing from a feature service hosted on ArcGIS online or have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do feature creation/editing from a feature service hosted on ArcGIS Online.

"Hosted web layers are designed for map visualization, editing, and query." http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/hosted-web-layers.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_5E584527C2BE44BB848B875F47B0434A

You can go to the REST endpoint for your feature service and look under 
"Supported Operations".  If you see "Apply Edits", that means your service can be edited.

You could also add the service to the ArcGIS Online Map Viewer and see if the layer allows for editing. 
http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/use-maps/edit-features.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to edit feature layers hosted in ArcGIS Online. There is plenty of documentation on this subject in the JSAPI docs. Here is one such example:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/ed_default_editingwidget.html